# Bring Focus to Modeless Userform without Clicking (Excel 2010 VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, userform

I am beginning to code a project that will open, login to and retrieve values from the Internet Explorer document.  The procedure pastes a value from an Excel spreadsheet into a proprietary automobile VIN decoding site, scrapes the resulting page for data, then writes those values to the spreadsheet.

That procedure is working great.  Since the page does return an error on occasion I designed an Excel userform that is called before the processing to ask what row of the worksheet to begin processing first.  The form is invoked with the following code:

```
Load frmStartRow
With frmStartRow  'Load start row form and await response
    .StartUpPosition = 0
    .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
    .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
     sndPlaySound32 "C:\Windows\Media\chimes.wav", 1&
     .Show vbModeless
End With
```

Invoking the form works as expected with one very key exception.  Because the IE browser has focus when the form is activated, the form appears but *has to be clicked* to be brought into focus.  The form contains a text box to accept the row number, and I want the form to appear on top of other windows, be modal and be able to accept data without users having to click on it.

I've tried APIs to bring the window to the top, toyed with vbModal vs. vb Modelss (as shown), tried to switch focus to the userform in the Activate event of the form and other approaches without success.  I am able to get the form to appear on top but it still *has to be clicked before it will accept data.*

The way the code is set now is the closest I've come.  With a vbModal userform I can't get it to appear on top, and that's even worse than having to click it.  I did find a reference to a .PopUp method or property which seemed like the trick, but it doesn't seem to be an option for Excel 2010.

In the final analysis I am trying to achieve a pop-up modal userform that is ready for data entry immediately after activation without a click being needed to bring focus to the form.  I appreciate any assistance!

Code used to invoke IE:

```
Dim objIEVIN

Set objIEVIN = New InternetExplorerMedium

With objIEVIN
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.fleet.ford.com/maintenance/vin-decoder/"
    Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop  'Wait for page loading to complete
End With
```

Siddharth Rout's comments had me thinking about the IE object's role in this issue.  If I initially set the IE object's .Visible = False, then invoke the userform and set .Visible = True after the userform closes, the userform behaves as expected.

I am using dual monitors and read yesterday of problems with such setups.  I get the same results if I run both Excel and IE on the same screen.  I also get the same results when I run the application from my laptop (single display).  I wanted to mention this since it is possibly involved in the issue.

Comment: You could send ie in the back? or keep it invisible?

Comment: I can execute the IE session without it being visible.  That does solve the problem (tried that approach yesterday) however it is tremendously helpful to be able to see what is happening since each iteration takes some time to process.  I've tried bringing Excel to the front but that didn't solve the problem.  How would I send the IE object to the back?

Comment: Is the soundplay gettig in the way? Also, if you're using the default instance of the UserForm, I don't think you need to Load it... The default form is pre-declared, so it is always loaded, it's just not shown.

Comment: It was a good thought.  I commented-out the SoundPlay line.  Same thing:  Excel comes up, the form is there only it has to be clicked.

I have to believe what I want to have happen is within the expected behavior of a userform.  Seems as if I've had the intended behavior with every other userform I have designed in the past.

Comment: How are you calling the code for IE? From within the form?, Before the form is launched? After the form is launched?

Comment: The sequence is:  Invoke IE | Navigate to logon page | Enter credentials and logon | Click through Terms page | VIN decode page appears | Show userform | Retrieve starting row & close form | Retrieve VIN from matching worksheet row | Enter VIN in decode text box and process...

Comment: Why do you need the show the UserForm in the middle of your workflow?  Why not just get the range information from the user *before* you invoke the browser?

Comment: @Comintern:  That's a valid observation and would address the issue with this particular userform.  However, I am anticipating needing to employ userforms elsewhere in this same application and doubt I'll be able to adjust the workflow around them all.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `SetForegroundWindow` and `SendKeys` seems to work:

```
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
                        (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Sub Example()
    Dim objIEVIN

    Set objIEVIN = New InternetExplorerMedium

    With objIEVIN
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "www.google.com"
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With

    Dim hWnd As Long
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
    hWnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", UserForm1.Caption)
    SetForegroundWindow hWnd
    SendKeys vbTab
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** The code above only seems to work if there hasn't been any keyboard input directed to the IE window. Since IE isn't an owned process (see the comments), one alternative is to simulate a mouse-click on the title bar of the window:

```
Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4

Private Type RECT
     Left As Long
     Top As Long
     Right As Long
     Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Long

Sub Example()
    Dim objIEVIN

    Set objIEVIN = New InternetExplorerMedium

    With objIEVIN
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "www.google.com"
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With

    Dim hwnd As Long
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
    hwnd = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", UserForm1.Caption)
    SetForegroundWindow hwnd

    Dim pos As RECT
    GetWindowRect hwnd, pos

    SetCursorPos pos.Left + 1, pos.Top + 1
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
    mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

End Sub
```

Note that this is basically intended as a proof of concept - for a production implementation you'd likely want to add a bunch of error handling around the API calls (and I'd personally cache and reset the mouse position).

Comment: As much as I loathe using SendKeys in my code, I did attempt your suggestion.  Unfortunately it does not behave on my machine as it does on yours.  I continue to have to click the form to enter data.  That said, I will try this code on my laptop to see whether it produces a different result.

Comment: @spacetanker - The window manager is pretty finicky about focus stealing.  In fact, IIR the only reason that `SetForegroundWindow` works in this instance is that the VBA is running with an attached debugger.  Normally user32 won't allow you to steal focus from a different process. Raymond Chen has a brief explanation of the underlying problem on his blog [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083).

Comment: @spacetanker - Just a thought - is the textbox on your UserForm the first thing item in the TabIndex?

Comment: Yes it is.  I have also tried frmStartRow.txtRow.SetFocus both from the main sub as well as within the form Activate event.  No effect.

Comment: @spacetanker - If you loathe using SendKeys, you'll *really* like this method - see the edit.

Comment: I've been down that route before too, though not on this project.  It is another option, though I keep thinking it shouldn't be necessary!  I'm in the process of carefully tracing the code and have found a couple of vestigial snips from prior debugging attempts.  It is possible that in the process of fixing this issue I have contradictory code.  Once I finish that up I'll repost my situation.

Answer (score 1):

> How would I send the IE object to the back? – spacetanker 7 mins ago

Simplest way to do it is to minimize it else you will have to use other API (`SetWindowPos`) to send it back. Try this

```
Private Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" Alias "ShowWindow" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Private Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2

Sub Sample()
    Dim ie As Object

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")

    ie.Visible = True

    apiShowWindow ie.hwnd, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED
End Sub
```

To return focus, you may try something like `TextBox1.SetFocus` after you minimize the window.

Comment: I tried this approach yesterday; it was among the APIs I experimented with.  In that circumstance I applied it against the Excel window to no avail.  I tried it again this morning with your code and, while it does minimize the IE window and brings the Excel window to the top, the userform still has to be clicked before data entry.

Comment: Did you try what I said `To return focus, you may try something like TextBox1.SetFocus after you minimize the window.`?

Comment: I tried that yesterday to no avail.  Just now tried it alongside your suggestions.  Still no joy.

Comment: Can I see your code which invokes the IE. Let me test it before I suggest anything else :)

Comment: Not in the comments please update your question. I would like to see the exact sequence on how the code runs

Comment: Added the code I'm using to invoke IE to original question above.

Comment: There is a healthy amount of code to logon to the site and advance to the VIN decoder page before the userform fires.  I wasn't certain how much of that you wanted to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AppActivate` *before* you show your form, with something like:

```
VBA.AppActivate(thisworkbook.Windows(1).Caption)
```

Comment: I tried AppActivate yesterday.  I couldn't remember the effect, so I tried it again just now.  It does bring the Excel workbook to the top, but again the userform isn't ready to accept data entry.  I'd attach a picture of the form before it is clicked and after to illustrate the difference, but I don't have that privilege and I'm not sure how helpful that would be anyway.  The form is on top, the default row I set in the textbox is selected, but I have to click on the form before I can change the value.

Answer (score 0):

After a day spent trying different approaches to resolve the problem my code was bloated with bits of code from different sources.  While attempting the techniques shared by Comintern and Siddharth Rout without success, I cleaned the code of all such remnants, saved and reopened the form.

I would swear the code and form were identical in every detail to their state before I began trying things to solve the problem.  That said, the clean up in some way got the focus issue working as it should.

I'm awarding the Solve to Comintern for his workflow suggestion, however the above is a brief compendium of the various things I have tried, so all involved get "Honorable Mention" and thanks for their time and consideration.